# SSRS 2019 - How to change the background color of the header fields?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

We have just upgraded to SSRS 2019 and now everyone hates the pure white background color of the header filters. It used to be a light blue color and much easier to read. Is there a way to change that color?

I can't find this question on SO. Other questions only refer to the color of report data. I've also read carefully through the RDL xml definition and cannot find any mention of the color, white, or ffffff. Is this just not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by the header filters? Do you mean the parameter section where you select the parameters? If this is what you mean, then search for "Branding" in SSRS

Comment: ... but bear in mind Branding is only available in Enterprise Edition.